# How long would it take until this corporation controls America?

Tags: alternate-reality, dystopia

I have a corporation called Hero. They've essentially 'taken over' all of America. I just need to know what the minimum amount of time it would take is.

When Hero was just starting out, back in 1974, they were a security company. They grew to be pretty big in a time span of about 10-15 years. Eventually, they were working with the government to guard things such as libraries, shelters, and transit centers in major cities. Then, they guarded museums, then stadiums. They started working in the smaller cities, in the towns, and then they were employed in all of the government buildings. At first, they worked alongside other government guards, but now they way outnumbered them.

They were making a ton of money. They had a special fund set up for them, and their leaders were some of the richest people in the world.

Somewhere alongside this, humans and their greed were remembered and they started paying off politicians to get away with more activities, such as replacing a small city's police force, or set up more security cameras than necessary, or put up propaganda.

Now, present day, the 1% own practically all of the wealth in America. The middle class has been practically eradicated, and most people are poverty-stricken. It's a dystopia characterized by poverty, constant surveillance, and constant, heavy fear. There is a smaller population, brutality, and other typical dystopia themes.

Assuming the world is, otherwise, ours, how long would this whole process take? Rating based on how realistic it is, and the shorter the time the better.

EDIT: The only difference between this world and ours is the existence and eventual rise of Hero. All influential figures, world events, and other such things are the same.

Comment: Does Mme Guillotine have a say at the end?

Comment: We need a better definition of "control" here (there's no need for any specific corporation to get to "1% dystopia"). And still looks too opinion-based to me.

Comment: This is not worls building, this is story writing.

Comment: Middle-managers for Hero, in a truly corrupt organization, cannot be trusted to be both loyal and competent. Hero's competent  executives will fight each other for promotions, money, and spite...and will hire subordinates based on loyalty. This will limit the company's ability to 'take over' anything.

Comment: if by government guards you mean the military simply outnumbering them doesn't count for a lot when they have access to tanks, aircraft and other instruments of war. You private security company has access to what? automatic rifles?

Comment: my control is basically meaning that politicians are puppets on strings in a small way, and that they're similar to google but, i don't know, a bit more malicious. i consider this worldbuilding as this is an integral part of my world and the history of it. i hadn't thought of that, @user535733, thank you. i'll figure out what to do about that later. BKlassen, thank you, once again had not thought of that. my current thoughts on it are that the military budget was not as much as real world's to begin with, and was reduced to fund hero even more meaning they don't have many of those instruments

Comment: Messrs. Vladimir Ilyich Ulyanov (alias "Lenin"), Lev Davidovich Bronstein (alias "Trotsky"), Joseph Jughashvili (alias "Stalin"), and their minions [took over the Russian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October_Revolution) (which was 6 times as large in area as the U.S.A.) in a little less than 5 years. Notably, they succeeded in acquiring the support of a large part of the army very early on. Also *very* notably they were a group of sociopathic fanatic criminals and not a corporation; corporations exist to *make money*, and ruling over a country of poor people is not profitable.

Comment: @AlexP **However**, anybody actually intent on taking over the country would undoubtedly form a corporation to do it, just for the protections against prosecution of *officers* that corporations currently enjoy. A privately held corporation does not answer to the public or have to disclose anything about its internal operations. And, as always, the way to stop infighting is with financial incentives, perks and privilege combined with ruthless discipline; and disposing of the *stupid* sociopaths. It works for real criminals. That is how the Kings of Europe did it too for centuries. It works!

Comment: The flaw here is the idea that police could "control" America.  Even if you employed 100% of all police, security guards, and soldiers, in the USA, the armed citizens outnumber you a hundred to one.  Now, they'd have to be pushed pretty far to take up arms, so you could probably keep nominal control for a long while... just so long as you never exercise it.

Comment: I apologize, Azelea, but this is POB.  How can you judge the right answer?  The company would face competition, all the more as they became successful.  Grassroots organizations fighting against their increasing oversight would spring up like daisies.  The process of becoming as powerful as you suggest is possible (even plausible for a good story), but the time required is 100% dependent on how you set up your story, culture, demographics, politics, religion, crises, etc., etc.  If you can provide criteria (I'm betting you can't without basically writing your story), I'll retract my VTC.

Comment: @JBH i did include what i'm rating on (plausibility, shorter amount of time) and i will edit it to specify that the existence of Hero is the only change between this world and ours. what else do i need to do?

Comment: That's my point: I don't know what you can do.  Plausibility?  Who's to say whether any answer is or isn't plausible?  Shortest time?  That's meaningless without a framework to judge plausibility.  A company theoretically controlled by the Illuminati could be said to need only a year to achieve the goal.  How do you judge if that is or isn't plausible?  This is an [open-ended question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654) without a objective answer or anywhere near the detail required to even take a crack at it, and as such isn't a good fit for SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it took roughly eighty years, from the end of Prohibition in 1933 to the effectively full-on wealth-control of the US Government, with legalized bribery (through SuperPacs, the Supreme Court decision allowing them occurred in 2010).

Stephen Colbert detailed the real-life rules of the SuperPac disaster on his comedy show (with real lawyers explaining it) and showed in detail how SuperPacs now allow politicians to personally pocket unlimited campaign contributions, tax-free no less, and do NOT have to disclose donors, amounts, etc. This allows legalized bribery in unlimited amounts to any politician with a few hundred bucks to set up a SuperPac.

Since the end of prohibition, there has been an increasing tendency of politicians voting to help provide legal cover to whichever criminals gave them enough money, and effectively extend the "privilege" of the very rich (even if criminally rich) and politically generous to be nearly immune to prosecution for any crime short of murder (and by now including crimes involving what once would have been considered murder). There has been a gradual increase of that for decades. Glenn Greenwald documents much of this in his book, *With Liberty and Justice for Some*.

I think your story can follow a similar dynamic; smart criminals and corporatists will not "take over" the country by force, they take over the country by paying a back-door tax, far **less** than what their income tax would be, but they use a few % of their profits to help elect politicians, from the ground up, friendly to their financial overtures, and will spend big to slander, compromise, frame and defeat any candidates that are NOT friendly to their overtures. Once they own a majority, they have control.

"From the ground up" means they finance the careers of police chiefs, city councilmen, mayors of small towns, state level legislators, governors, as well as national congressmen, senators and presidents. Half of this is to get these people to give them multi-million (even multi-billion) \$ contracts and business (as you suggested), knowing they (meaning the politicians) will get their fair cut of the millions, or "favors", that can range from sexcapades with high-end call girls to sweetheart "investment" deals in real-estate (a "distressed" seller sells the politician a \$250K house for \$150K), "used" cars (brand new cars bought and sold to the politician for the minimum legal price), hot stock market tips (when the fix is in), even hard to trace "gifts" (alcohol, entertainment systems, house re-modelings, vacations, etc).

Sometimes these bribes the form of after-the-fact jobs (lobbying positions, business partnerships requiring no investment from the former politician, "consultant" positions, etc). The bribers are consistent in these payoffs, even after the politician can no longer *directly* help them, because it is important for other, *sitting* politicians to see the briber takes care of their "helpers" once they leave office. These jobs and sweet deals are a form of advertising to still-active politicians.

Note they don't have to do this nationwide, they can start as small as a town, to start the public-money tap, and aggressively re-invest the profits into expanding their influence into the cities, then the State, then neighboring states, like a cancer, all the while collecting politicians that steadily increase the amount of public money flowing into their corporate bank accounts.

An important part of this scheme is to explicitly choose to support corruptible politicians. This can often be discerned by doing comprehensive background checks into their character.

This is important because it lets the bribers develop sticks to back up their carrots: Audio and film evidence of the politician doing compromising things, in particular sexual things like enjoying the services of prostitutes, but also things like getting illegally high, or getting drunk, taking explicit bribes, trips, gifts, or actually committing felonies. Just in case the bastard ever grows a conscience or balks at something particularly heinous; the bribers will want to show them a private screening of a convincing story.

If your Security company begins in today's legal landscape, and they are smart and ruthless, they could plausibly take over in 30 years or so. But beware, they will undoubtedly encounter resistance from the **current** owners, and I would not be surprised if it were lethal.

In America there were a lot of laws to be circumvented to engineer our current legally-sanctioned corruption (IMO obviously, and talking about **both** parties), so it took about 80 years.

Comment: What is making American democracy resilient is that while there are many ways for corporations and wealthy individuals to _influence_ political process, there is no reliable ways to _control_ it. A politician can switch his sponsors (and even political parties) on a whim, and there is virtually nothing that stops him from doing so. Thus, pushing a politician to do something that goes against the will of other sponsors (you mentioned "current owners"?) becomes prohibitively expensive.

Comment: To make it a game-changer, corrupt corporation should cultivate something like [Tammany Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tammany_Hall) on national scale, ensuring that no outsider, no matter the budget, can win an election.

Comment: @Alexander Welcome to *extremely* weak security on electronic voting devices with absolutely zero means of verifying the vote by paper trail. They can and have been hacked by high-school students enough to change the vote. We have reports of districts with less than 200 votes casting over ***600 votes*** and that not even being investigated. Also welcome to widespread and unchecked voter suppression tactics, and widespread gerrymandering. There are plenty of ways for parties to control the votes, but Corporations own majorities in **both** parties, they don't have to *control* the vote.

Comment: "Corporation**s** own majorities" (I mostly agree with you and only going to highlight one letter to stress the point where I seem to disagree).

Comment: @Alexander Corporation**s** agree on an enormous number of issues; like immunity for officers from prosecution (even in cases of negligent death or intentional acts resulting in death, like pollution of water supplies with toxic chemicals); minimizing and eliminating taxes, increasing subsidies, minimal fines for defrauding investors, engaging in money laundering, and so on. The split between the parties is on **social** issues that in most circumstances sociopathic corporations don't care about, unless it hurts their bottom line. e.g. Why should they care if abortion is legal or not?

Comment: Our question is not about pushing any particular policies (however unanimously corporations may agree on them), the question is about just one corporation consolidating control.

Comment: @Alexander And I think ONE corporation could do it by these methods, if that is what they set out to do, and instead of growing fat and happy with the money, persistently re-invested everything into getting more contracts and buying more influence. This competes with *multiple* corporations because *they* are driven by short term greed, while the new corp Hero plays the long game for total control, redirecting all profits into growth of their political control (and keeping current officers and political properties reasonably happy). Other corps buy just enough power, Hero buys all they can.

Comment: as long as influence is "for sale", one corporation can never buy is all, not likely even buy 50% of it. Top US corporation, Walmart, has revenues just about 2.5% of US GDP. To control the politics, a corporation has to be bigger than Standard Oil was in Gilded Age.

Comment: @Alexander They don't have to buy it all, and if you say it is *unlikely* they can buy 50% of it, then you admit the possibility. And your premise is wrong, there are two parts: Bribes can be paid, but also the corporation can wreak vengeance on politicians by funding challengers, and the OP allows "brutality" by this corporation, I don't take violent threats or assassination from their toolbox. Don't forget this is fiction, it only needs to be ***plausible,*** and if you admit there is a *chance* of controlling over 50% , then this game over.

Comment: of course this is fiction, but with present antitrust laws, the possibility is 0. We need to transition from modern day USA to a dystopian USA to make it a reality. Otherwise, as I said - the biggest corporation controls only 2.5% of economy. They may pay bribes and fund any politicians, no problem, but their political budget is actually very small.

Comment: @Alexander Antitrust laws need to be prosecuted, and those are already out of fashion. Even bribery has been effectively legalized via Superpacs, and the OP specifically allows brutality. All Walmart has to do is buy the AG, not that hard to do. Finally, antitrust laws are about **business** not controlling politicians, and once you control the politicians, they will exempt you from any laws you don't like about hostile take-overs. They can refuse to prosecute you, or judges will dismiss the case others bring against you. They can do that with *murder*, what recourse does your target have?

Comment: I'm afraid you are missing my point, or at least a part of it. I'm not saying that corporations can't play dirty. I'm saying that one corporation can't outplay all the others. For example, in 1930s, notorious Al Capone's Outfit did not CONTROL the organized crime in Chicago (though it was indeed the biggest player). There is a huge difference between being able to play the system and actually controlling it.

Comment: @Alexander Then I am afraid you are missing my point, this is fiction. It doesn't matter how Hero gets their success, if politicians can be controlled by money, blackmail, threats of violence and/or funding their opposition, sexual rewards or anything else, then it is ***plausible*** that one rich corporation can control multiple politicians, and therefore plausible they can control 50% of them. Laws won't matter, the politicians are already corrupt, and IRL selling out for less than a million, not billions. This isn't the world of Capone, when political shame still mattered. Not anymore.

Comment: @Alexander Especially if it is privately owned, does not answer to shareholders or the SEC, and is devoting its billions of dollars worth of profits to acquiring this control by any means necessary, using both legal and brutally illegal methods, as the situation for each politician demands.

Comment: Ok, I will agree if in this fiction one corporation is playing dirty, while everyone else is playing more or less nice.